# I need to get the JSON schema from an API

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter/Dart and I want to get data from an API. I don't know how to get the JSON schema from the API. I don't find it in the documentation.

This is the API I want to connect to. https://rapidapi.com/realtymole/api/realty-mole-property-api

I have written code from an example using this JSON: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
but this site already has the json available so I can convert the json to dart.

How do I use this API in my flutter project?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you receive when you called the API on your flutter project?

Comment: ??? Did you look at that documentation page?  Did you notice the lower right-hand pane, where it says "Code Snippets", there's another tab labeled "Example Responses" that includes a subtab labeled "Schema"?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did see the code snippets and example responses but the code snippets are not in Dart and I am not sure how to use the example responses. Should I build the class from the example response? Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these packages to connect with API and get response.

- [Dio package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)
- [http Package](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

And after getting your JSON response use can use [Quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/) to convert JSON into dart model. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have used the http package to test accessing an API and get the json response where I can then convert the json to a Dart model. However, how do I get a response without knowing the json schema that is returned from the API?

Comment: I think I was able to convert the json to dart model. I will try the code and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Quicktype](https://quicktype.io/) service to generate the required Dart models out of the example JSON responses of different endpoints provided in the API documentation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).